# bitcoin-cli "Could not connect to the server"

Tags: bitcoind

Brand new Raspberry Pi mainnet node following this walkthrough:

https://medium.com/@meeDamian/bitcoin-full-node-on-rbp3-revised-88bb7c8ef1d1

When I run this command:

`bitcoin-cli -rpcuser=username -rpcpassword=password -rpcport=8332 getblockchaininfo`

I receive the error:

`error: Could not connect to the server 127.0.0.1:8332`

When I tail debug.log, the node appears to be fully sync'd and picking up new blocks

My bitcoin.conf file is:

`#is required for Fail2Ban
logips=1`

`#magic RBP optimizations
maxconnections=40
maxuploadtarget=5000`

`upnp=1`

`server=1
rpcuser='username'
rpcpassword='password'
rpcport='8332'`

`walletrbf=1`

My apologies if my formatting is bad here, couldn't figure out how to get the .conf to paste as a block of text. Thank you for any ideas on what I'm doing wrong!

Comment: I guess checking your debug.log in your Bitcoin datadir ~/.bitcoin may give you some answers

Comment: I think having single quotes in the values for `rpcuser`, `rpcpassword`, and `rpcport` in your bitcoin.conf file is causing problems. Try removing those quotes and restart bitcoind.

Comment: The single quotes were it -- thanks so much!

Answer (score 1):

I encountered this error message when I have not started `bitcoind.exe`.

Starting `bitcoind.exe` solved the problem.